# How to eloquently keep a track of all warnings/messages during an api call and return the same along with the output in python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, logging, software-design

**Method 1**

```
warnings = list()
messages = list()

def calculate(a, b, method):
    if isinstance(a, float):
        warnings.append(f"a:{a} is float, converting it to int!")
        a = int(a)
    ...
    result = a + b
    messages.append(f"result is {result}")
    return result, {"warnings": warnings, "messages": messasges}
```

In the example above, I have a simple function calculate() and I am keeping a track of all the warnings/messages during this run and then returning the same with the actual result because let's say I want to display these warnings/messages to the end user on UI along with the actual result.

Another better way to do the same would be:

**Method 2**

```
class Alerts():
    def __init__():
        self.warnings = list()
        self.messages = list()

def calculate(a, b, method):
    alrt = Alerts()
    if isinstance(a, float):
        alrt.warnings.append(f"a:{a} is float, converting it to int!")
        a = int(a)
    ...
    result = a + b
    alrt.messages.append(f"result is {result}")
    return result, alrt
```

In Method 2, it's more convenient to keep track of all messages/warnings by defining them in a single object and this will also allow to write some custom methods in Alert() class for formatting messages/warnings, et cetera.

**Potential Issue**

If there are several method calls involved in an api call, then I would have to create/maintain this Alert() object everywhere and/or toss it around in my methods to keep a track of ALL warnings/messages in one single object.

**Is one of the above methods a good way to achieve this? Can it be made more eloquent?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is this API call something that needs to run asynchronously? Are there separate server and client sides? You might be better off using lockable storage to dump aggregated status into. Otherwise, being an object, you can pass a reference to the accumulator to each computation step.

Comment: Yes, the API call needs to run asynchronously. Yes, there are separate server and client sides. I can use a lockable storage but that means processing only single (or finite) number of requests at a time. Passing a reference to the accumulator is what I found the most convenient to use after some thinking. Basically, I will create an object of Alerts() once in my outermost function (i.e function closest to end point) and then pass its reference down to any other method calls I make during that api run.

Comment: @CodeMantle: You can check my solution below. Any comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, below is the most eloquent way I could come up with. calculate() is my api function, sum() is one of the internal method calls in the api run.

```
# for handling results of any api, including errors/warnings/messages
class ResultHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.warnings = list()
        self.messages = list()
        self.errors = list()
        self.result = dict()

    def append_traceback(self):
        pass

# to wrap the output of an api call in ResultHandler() object
def wrap_output(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        rh = ResultHandler()
        rh.messages.append("1: i am wrap_output!")
        try:
            kwargs["rh"] = rh
            rh.result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            rh.append_traceback()
        rh.messages.append("2: i am wrap_output!")
        return rh
    return wrapper

# an internal method call
def sum(rh):
    print("sum")
    rh.messages.append("i am sum!")
    return 1

# api function
@wrap_output
def calculate(*args, **kwargs):
    rh = kwargs["rh"]

    rh.messages.append("1: i am calculate!")

    out = sum(*args, **kwargs)

    rh.messages.append("2: i am calculate!")
    return out

# calling api
o = calculate()
print(o.messages)
```